# How to find required unique result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table 'topic' and 'subcategory'

I am using this query--

```
Select * from `subcategory` as s 
Inner join `topic` as f
WHERE s.`Subcategory_id` = f.`Subcategory_id
```

My result shows like

**Category_id       Subcategory_id     Post_id     time**

```
    2        2.3         4    2012-12-01
    1        1.5         5    2013-01-20
    1        1.3         6    2013-03-18
```

There's also other columns... but all I want is to select the latest Post_id and Subcategory_id of one Category_id ... that means here Category 1 has two Subcategory it will select only the latest(here 1.3) and same result all the time for all Category when database will grown larger. What will be the next query or how could I change the existing query to gain my desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Post_Id, Subcategory_Id from subcategory as s, topic as t where 
   s.Subcategory_id = t.Subcategory_id and time = (
      SELECT Max(time) from subcategory as s1, topic as t1 where 
         s1.Subcategory_id = t1.Subcategory_id and s1.Category_id = s.Category_id
   );
```

Something like that, I think, will work.

Comment: Though your sql shows an error, but thanks after combining last part of your sql with mine it shows my desired result.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY whatever column determines "the latest"
```

e.g.

```
SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY TIME DESCENDING
```

Or in case of mysql:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY TIME DESCENDING LIMIT 1
```

Comment: what do you mean by Top 1?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp - oops mysql does not seem to support this. However it supports "limit": http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html, I eddit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Join your topic table with following query:

```
SELECT s.* FROM subcategory s
    Inner JOIN (SELECT s1.Category_id,
                 MAX(s1.time1) AS max_time
                 FROM subcategory s1
                 GROUP BY s1.Category_id) y 
ON y.Category_id = s.Category_id AND y.max_time = s.time1
```